# Linking two shared libraries with some of the same symbols

Tags: c, unix, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I link with two different shared libraries. Both libraries define some symbols that share a name but have different implementations. I can't make each library use its own implementation over the other.

For example, both libraries define a global function `bar()` that each calls internally. Library one calls it from `foo1()` and library two calls it from `foo2()`.

Lib1.so:

```
T bar
T foo1()     // calls bar()
```

Lib2.so:

```
T bar
T foo2()     // calls bar()
```

If I link my application against Lib1.so and then Lib2.so the bar implementation from Lib1.so is called even when calling `foo2()`. If on the other hand, I link my application against Lib2.so and then Lib1.so, then bar is always called from Lib2.so.

Is there a way to make a library always prefer its own implementation above any other library?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this:

- Pass **`-Bsymbolic`** or **`-Bsymbolic-functions`** to the linker. This has a global effect: every reference to a global symbol (of function type for `-Bsymbolic-functions`) that can be resolved to a symbol in the library is resolved to that symbol. With this you lose the ability to interpose internal library calls to those symbols using LD_PRELOAD. **The symbols are still exported**, so they can be referenced from outside the library.
- Use a **version script** to mark symbols as *local* to the library, e.g. use something like: `{local: bar;};` and pass `--version-script=versionfile` to the linker. **The symbols are *not* exported.**
- Mark symbols with an approppiate **visibility** ([GCC info page for visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bvisibility_007d-attribute-2535)), which will be either *hidden*, *internal*, or *protected*. ***protected*** visibility symbols **are exported as `.protected`**, ***hidden* symbols are not exported**, and ***internal* symbols are not exported** and you compromise not to call them from outside the library, even indirectly through function pointers.

You can check which symbols are exported with `objdump -T`.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me please whether this applies to clang as well?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to create two 'wrapper' shared libs, one for each of your existing libs. Each one should be built with a --dynamic-list that lists only a few non-conflicting symbols that define an API. You will also need -Bsymbolic to avoid any global combination.

It might be less stressful to access the resulting libs via dlopen with suitable options, as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just the -Bsymbolic option (passed to the linker using the -Wl option) for both shared library linkings solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is using macro to change namespace.

**Prerequisites**

- All elements (functions, classes, global variables, ...) are in a namespace.
- The library doesn't heavily depend on macros in headers.

**Solution**

- When compiling the library, define macro with namespace name to define it to something different. For example if the namespace is LibNS, use `-DLibNS=LibNSv1` for one case and `-DLibNS=LibNSv2` for the other.
- When using libraries in the code, define macro according your current situation;

  ```
  #define LibNS LibNSv1
  #include "my_lib.h"
  #undef LibNS
  ```

**Reasons why use this instead of other solutions**

- When the problematic library is used (at least partially) in header files (for example templates, inlines, ...); when you include them in your executable's code, resolver doesn't have idea whether these functions should be called from Lib1.so or Lib2.so.
- Your compiler has poor/none support for other solutions (shouldn't happen with our intel/amd 32/64 bit CPUs, but it seems from Google search that some other platforms might have the problem).

**Potential problems**

- It might be problematic to use both version in one cpp file of your executable; `#include "my_lib.h"` probably uses macro to protect against multiple-inclusion and undefining them to avoid this might cause lots of different problems (library author might change the macro name in the future, header defines some other macros, etc.).
- The name `LibNS` might be used for something else in the library (variable, function, etc.); in that case, this name will be also changed to `LibNSv1` or `LibNSv2`. This might lead to other problems depending on the library and how it's used.

**Notes**

- This isn't meant to replace currently accepted answer (from ninjalj; feel free to copy-paste it), but extend it with another approach.
- Main reason why I posted this answer is that I encountered this problem today, but answer didn't help due to problematic code being in header files.
- My source: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/03/static-linking-c-plus-plus/