# Force mapping between symbols and shared libraries

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have an executable with four shared libraries and the dependency tree look like this: Executable *app* does a *dlopen* of `foo.so` and `bar.so`. `foo.so` in turn links to `fooHelper.so` and `bar.so` links to `barHelper.so`.

Now, the issue is that `fooHelper.so` and `barHelper.so` have some of the same symbols. For instance, let us say we have a `func` with different implementations in `fooHelper.so` and `barHelper.so`. Is there a way to force `foo.so` to use `fooHelper.so`'s implementation and `bar.so` to use `barHelper.so`'s? What happens at present is that depending on the order of linking of the helpers, only one of the implementations of `func` is used by both `foo.so` and `bar.so`. This is because of the default Unix linkage model, if the definition of a symbol is already loaded, then any other definitions from shared libraries loaded subsequently are just discarded. Basically, `func` will be picked up from the helper library linked first. I need a way to explicitly specify the appropriate mapping without changing the source code of the shared libraries.

I'm working on Linux with g++ 4.4.

Comment: If you compile those libraries from source, you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to force foo.so to use fooHelper.so's implementation and bar.so to use barHelper.so's?

Yes: that's what `RTLD_LOCAL` is for (when `dlopen`ing `foo.so` and `bar.so`).

```
RTLD_LOCAL
  This is the converse of RTLD_GLOBAL, and the default if neither flag
  is specified. Symbols defined in this library are not made available
  to resolve references in subsequently loaded libraries.
```

Answer (score 0):

If both funcs happen to be in the same name-space, you're in a bit of trouble - if you are programming in C. The term to look for is "function overloading". There have been previous discussions on this topic, e.g. this one:
[function overloading in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c)

EDIT: http://litdream.blogspot.de/2007/03/dynamic-loading-using-dlopen-api-in-c.html

Comment: Ah, should have made it explicit, I'm working with C++. Don't think overloading is relevant though, `func` has the same signature in both `fooHelper.so` and `barHelper.so`. I'll edit the question to make this clear.