# Relocations R_386_JUMP_SLOT of local symbols in shared object

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I'm digging in dynamic relocation process and i created a very simple shared object:

```
int func_1(int v)
{
    v + 10;
}

int func_2()
{
   return func_1(10);
}
```

compiled as:

```
gcc -fPIC -c libtest.c
gcc -shared -nostdlib -o libtest.so libtest.o
```

If we look at dynamic relocations for the shared object:

```
$ objdump -R libtest.so

libtest.so:    file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
00002000 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   func_1
```

there is a R_386_JUMP_SLOT for the symbol `func_1` so the call in the `func_2` is resolved by PLT. I can't figure out the reason for this...If `func_1` is declared as private (`static`) the relocation disappears and the call is resolved (by static linker) with a relative branch. Why passing from PLT is better than a relative jump?

Comment: As @Miroslav wrote, that's to allow interposing. If you don't want to restrict use of `func1` to a single file (translation unit) but still don't want to export the symbol, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols/6540059#6540059

Answer (score 1):

With PLT you can override the call from `func_2` to call to some other version of `func_1` at runtime.  For example via `LD_PRELOAD`.  With static keyword, you just hardcoded your own private version of `func_1`.  It's flexibility vs. small run-time overhead.