# Is there more overhead to calling a function in a separate compilation unit?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I know that there's more overhead to calling a function in a DSO due to the double jump. Is there more overhead in calling a function in a separate compilation unit compared with calling one in the same compilation unit (assuming it's not inlined in both cases)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, they will be the same, not countin inlining or other global optimization oportunities. But there may be subtle differences depending on the architecture.

For example, in Linux/Unix, the issue is not between functions of different CU, but whether the function you are calling has external linkage or not:

```
void foo() {}
void bar()
{ foo(); }
```

Or:

```
static void foo() {}
void bar()
{ foo(); }
```

If this code is compiled into a shared object (but not into an executable!), then the external `foo()` might be overriden by another shared object (via `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD` for example), but the static one cannot. Thus, the call to external functions inside shared object, even from the same CU, must be done using a relocatable jump.

In Windows, however, there is no such thing as `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD`, so there is no such difference.

Comment: In a library you can sometimes improve this if you change the visibility of the symbol to be limited to the library. On gcc-compatible compilers this can be done by adding `__attribute__((visibility ("hidden")))` to the function prototype. This doesn't help on all operating systems and architectures, but it can sometimes improve things and doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Art: Right! My preference is to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` and then add `__attribute__((visibility("default"))` only to the symbols to be exported.

Comment: I see there's a linker option, -Bsymbolic, which makes references within a shared library bind to the symbols within that library. I suppose this way you don't have to change the visibility if you don't want to.

Comment: @RossLagerwall: Oh, I didn't know that. I've just tried it, and it looks like it does exactly what you say (I still like the `-fvisibility=hidden`, but for other reasons).

Comment: @RossLagerwall: yes, you could even mark symbols as local to the library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540059/371250

Answer (score 0):

The only possible overhead I see is with variable-length jump macros, which might always have the maximum length when jumping across compilation units (unless the linker optimizes that).