# Linkin two shared library with same symbol name but different symbol type

Tags: c, linux, g++, export, shared-libraries

I want to link two shared libraries that both two libraries have same symbol name but different symbol type.

For example, there are **liba.so** and **libb.so** libraries that consist of two files a.c/b.c and b_wrapper.c/a_wrapper.c

a.c

```
__thread int var;
```

a_wrapper.cpp

```
extern __thread int var;
```

**liba.so**

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c a.c -o a.o 
$ g++ -fPIC -c a_wrapper.cpp -o a_wrapper.o -std=c++11
$ g++ -fPIC -shared  -o liba.so a.o a_wrapper.o -std=c++11
```

b.c

```
int var;
```

b_wrapper.c

```
extern int var;
```

**libb.so**

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c b.c -o b.o 
$ g++ -fPIC -c b_wrapper.cpp -o b_wrapper.o -std=c++11
$ g++ -fPIC -shared  -o libb.so b.o b_wrapper.o -std=c++11
```

then link liba.so and libb.so to top.c file, I get some error message

```
$ g++ top.cpp -ldl -o exe ./liba.so ./libb.so  -std=c++11

/usr/bin/ld: var: TLS definition in ./liba.so section .tdata mismatches non-
TLS definition in ./libb.so section .bss
./libb.so: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think the problem is because `var` in a.c is defined in thread local storage ***bss(tbss)***, but `var` in b.c is defined in normal ***bss***.

---

I have read this post [Linking two shared libraries with some of the same symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols)

and try `-Bsymbolic`, `--version-script` and `-fvisibility=hidden`, but all these methods can not achieve my goal.

`-Bsymbolic` : I used it when creating liba.so and libb.so, but when I linked liba.so and libb.so I still got same error message described as above

`--version-script` and  `-fvisibility=hidden` :  I can't let `var` variable become local to one file(a.c) since other files(a_wrapper.cpp) will extern and use that variable

Is there any way that I can link two shared libraries that has some same symbol name but different symbol type?