# How to generate linker warning for same function defined in different linked shared libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, linker

The situation is similar to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols) i.e. a function with the same name is defined differently in two separate .so libs which are then linked to the same executable where the function may be called. If the source files of the libs were being compiled together, the linker would have complained of something like "multiple definition ...". Is it possible to make the linker give some warning that the same function is defined in different .so libs being linked in the given scenario?

Comment: The short answer is no, it isn't possible.  It isn't desirable, either.  Consider the consequences if there was such a warning.

Comment: Well it may be useful for the case I just described.