# Is it possible to link a shared library (from another shared library), without making its symbols globally visible?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, elf

Suppose `libA`, which I have full control of, depends on `libC.so.2`. Meanwhile, a third party `libB`, with which my `libA` might co-exist within the same process, depends on `libC.so.1`.

Normal dynamic linking doesn't work because either `libA` or `libB` would receive wrong implementation for symbols in `libC`. How can I make `libA` works with `libB`, with minimal modification of the building pipeline of `libA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are ok with changing names of symbols from `libC.so.2` you can use [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so)'s renaming functionality. E.g. to change all `libC.so.2` symbols to have `MYPREFIX_` prefix:

```
$ cat mycallback.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void *mycallback() {
  void *h = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libxyz.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
  if (h)
    return h;
  fprintf(stderr, "dlmopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
  exit(1);
}
$ implib-gen.py --dlopen-callback=mycallback --symbol_prefix=MYPREFIX_ libC.so.2
$ ... # Link your app with libC.so.2.tramp.S, libC.so.2.init.c and mycallback.c, keep libC.so.1 unchanged
```

Function names in `libC.so.2`'s header will need to be updated as well (often that's a simple `s///` in vim).

Implib.so works by generating a bunch of wrappers for each symbol in problematic library (in this case `libC.so.2`) and forwarding calls to their actual implementation internally (via `dlsym`).

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and tested a bit ...

First, the changing `libC`:

```
// libC1.c => libC.so.1
int c(void) { return 21; }
```

```
// libC2.c => libC.so.2
int c(void) { return 42; }
```

Then `libA` and `libB`:

```
// libA.c => libA.so | gcc -fPIC -shared -o libA.so libA.c -l:libC.so.1 -L.
extern int c(void);
int a(void) { return c(); }
```

```
// libB.c => libB.so | gcc -fPIC -shared -o libB.so libB.c -l:libC.so.2 -L.
extern int c(void);
int b(void) { return c(); }
```

Note that above in both cases I specifiy the correct `.so` file directly (`-l:libC.so.1` and `-l:libC.so.2`).  Now both `libA` and `libB` refer to the correct `libC`, but there's a problem: **Both `libC`s export the symbol `c`!**

Thus ...

```
extern int a(void);
extern int b(void);

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("a => %d, b => %d\n", a(), b());
}
```

... will happily print `a => 21, b => 21`.  The reason is that once the dynamic linker loads one of the `libC`s, the symbol `c` (which is undefined in *both* `libA` and `libB`) is resolved (for both `libA` and `libB`) to the one loaded.

## `dlopen` seems to be the only way

There are two approaches:

### Modify the application using `libA` and `libB`

Load both libraries on your own using `dlopen`, `RTLD_LOCAL` makes symbols loaded (thus also symbols of dependencies of the loaded library) *not* visible to the application (or later calls to `dlopen`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int (*a)(void);
int (*b)(void);


int main() {
  void * const a_handle = dlopen("libA.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
  // you could dlopen("libC.so.2", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL) here to "select"
  // the correct symbol `c` for the following, too.
  void * const b_handle = dlopen("libB.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
  assert(a_handle); // real error handling here please!
  assert(b_handle);
  *(void **)(&a) = dlsym(a_handle, "a");
  *(void **)(&b) = dlsym(b_handle, "b");
  assert(a); // real error handling here please!
  assert(b);
  printf("a => %d, b => %d\n", a(), b());
}
```

Then compiling, linking and running above (`main2.c`) gives

```
# gcc main2.c -ldl
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
a => 21, b => 42
```

### Modify `libA`

In the source code of your `libA`, wherever you call a function `funC` from `libC`, you need to replace that call with a call to `funC_impl` with:

```
int (*funC_impl)(char *, double); // for a funC(char *, double) which returns an int

// and somewhere during initialization:

void * const c_handle = dlopen("libC.so.2", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
// check c_handle != NULL
*(void **)(&funC_impl) = dlsym(c_handle, "funC");
// check for errors! (dlerror)
```

And all that for every function, of course ... and of course you cannot control `libB` in that way.

## [Allegedly `-Bsymbolic` might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540059/1116364), but I wasn't able to get it to work

---

If one runs `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. LD_DEBUG=all ./a.out 2>&1` (for the version at the top of the answer) then this is part of the output:

```
     10545:     Initial object scopes
     10545:     object=./a.out [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:     
     10545:     object=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:      scope 1: linux-vdso.so.1
     10545:     
     10545:     object=./libA.so [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:     
     10545:     object=./libB.so [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:     
     10545:     object=/nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:     
     10545:     object=./libC.so.1 [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:     
     10545:     object=./libC.so.2 [0]
     10545:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libA.so ./libB.so /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 ./libC.so.1 ./libC.so.2 /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     10545:     
     10545:     object=/nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     10545:      no scope
     10545:
```

The issue is that for both `libA` and `libB` the initial scope contains the libraries `libC.so.1` and `libC.so.2` **in that order**.  So when resolving the symbol `c` in each of `libA` and `libB`, it first looks into `libC.so.1`, finds the symbol and is done with it.

Now "all" that's missing is a way to change this "initial object scope".