# Linking two 3rd-party shared libraries with some of the same symbols

Tags: linux, linker, g++

Similar situation to the post [Linking two shared libraries with some of the same symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols), my program a.cpp is linked with two different **3rd-party** dynamic libraries, say, lib1.so and lib2.so.

lib1.so contains function

```
foo();
```

lib2.so contains function

```
bar(); // it calls its own foo();
foo();
```

My compilation command is

```
g++ a.cpp lib1.so lib2.so
```

The reason I put lib1.so in front of lib2.so is that my a.cpp needs `foo()` in lib1.so and `bar()` in lib2.so. If we do nothing, `bar()` in lib2.so will call `foo()` in lib1.so when the program is running. If I change the order, my program will not be able to call `foo()` in lib1.so. If lib1.so and lib2.so were built by myself, I could use the solution in the mentioned post at the beginning of this question. However, I cannot control both libs and there are many APIs in both libs.

How can I specify the linking options for my program so lib2.so calls its own functions during runtime?