# CMake: How to explicitly place the linked library (or compilation flags) at the specific location of the compiling command?

Tags: cmake

It is very easy to add compilation flags, linked libraries for any targets using CMake. However, it is very difficulty to order them.

Say, I have the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(a a.cpp)
target_compile_options(a PRIVATE ${FLAG1})
target_compile_options(a PRIVATE ${FLAG2})
target_link_libraries(a PRIVATE ${LIB1})
target_link_libraries(a PRIVATE ${LIB2})
```

I know that those flags and libs will appear in my final compilation command. However, I cannot know the order of them. Is there a easy way to specify the order of them?

I know there is some not-very-clean way to arrange the lib order by specifying the dependency of ${LIB1} and ${LIB2} using `target_link_libraries`, but it is not always work expecially when ${LIB1} and ${LIB2} are third-party libraries.

Comment: Using `target_link_libraries` *is* the clean way to do that. If a third-party library doesn't specify the libs it links to properly then you should file a bug report with their vendor, but you can also manually add the missing `target_link_libraries` call for that library as a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: I think using `target_link_libraries` to build the order makes the process complicated. Suppose I want to place the lib to the end of the command. I need to write as many `taget_link_libraries` as the number of libraries in front of it. Moreover, it is not possible to use `taget_link_libraries` if the target is a file name.

Comment: "I think using `target_link_libraries` to build the order makes the process complicated." - But `target_link_libraries` makes the configuration **scalable**: it will work when one adds new libraries to your project, or when one adds your project as a subproject to other one. "it is not possible to use `taget_link_libraries` if the target is a file name." - Just wrap the target into IMPORTED library, so it will be usable with `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: BTW, `target_link_libraries(a PRIVATE ${LIB1} ${LIB2})` will pass LIB1 and LIB2 libraries to the linker in exactly that order: LIB1, then LIB2. Your code achieves the same effect. What is a problem?

Comment: "Suppose I want to place the lib to the end of the command." Why do you care whether it is at the end or somewhere in the middle if the relative order of dependencies is correct, i.e. a dependency will be linked after its dependees. Because if every library specifies its dependencies correctly this is what you'll get. And it just works.

Comment: LIB1 is from company 1, which provide symbol, say, xxx. LIB2 is from company 2, which also provides symbol xxx. The symbol xxx I would like to use is from company 1. I cannot change the contents of LIB1 and LIB2. One way to address this problem is that I tell cmake that LIB1 depends on LIB2, so LIB1 is in front of LIB2. If LIB1 and LIB2 refer to a single library file, it is fine to use `target_link_libraries`. As it is just a few lines of code.

Comment: However, LIB1 is an interface target which contains a set of actual libraries. LIB2 is in a similar situation. Moreover, LIB1 and LIB2 have their own LIB{1|2}Config.cmake. It means that I don't know what exactly LIB1's and LIB2's cmake actually set in addition to the library they load. If I just say `target_link_libraries(LIB1 INTERFACE LIB2)`, it does not work. If I dig into both .cmake files and found out what library files they load, it complicates everything, because it basically means I need to rewrite both .cmake.

Comment: "BTW, target_link_libraries(a PRIVATE ${LIB1} ${LIB2}) will pass LIB1 and LIB2 libraries to the linker in exactly that order: LIB1, then LIB2. " It indeed is. However, if the entire project contains a very complicated dependency graph, it is hard to guarantee LIB1 is in front of LIB2 even writing as what you suggested. This is because target a may depend on other targets that depend on LIB1 or LIB2. The better way would be to set the dependency between LIB1 and LIB2 ahead.

Comment: "LIB1 is from company 1, which provide symbol, say, xxx. LIB2 is from company 2, which also provides symbol xxx. " Even if you get to link this correctly,  if it makes a difference which symbol is picked you have undefined behavior which almost surely will cause weird crashes or other "unexplainable" behavior when code in LIB2 suddenly uses xxx from LIB1 but expects to use its own version.

Comment: "LIB2 suddenly uses xxx from LIB1 but expects to use its own version." Although I cannot find the official doc from the linker and gcc talking about this issue, from my several test results, LIB2 will only pick up xxx in LIB2 but not in LIB1. Please let me know if the official doc is saying the opposite.

Comment: That depends on whether these are static or shared libraries, whether or not xxx was inlined everywhere it is used in LIB2 or not, and whether or not the shared libraries were built with symbolic links or not.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538501/linking-two-shared-libraries-with-some-of-the-same-symbols for some more information on how to deal with this situation.